# PHP dynamic Mailchimp list

Tags: javascript, php, mailchimp

I am using mailchimp and I have different lists on mail chimp. I have a dynamic webpage using PHP and for every different link, I have created a new list. I have a database table with the list urls and I have copied a code that mailchimp provides and changed url of form onsubmit to new url and also in javascript but it does not work. It only works with url through which the code was generated.

Here is the code that mailchimp provides

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://worldacademy.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3aff75083c84f012673478808&amp;id=175e779a1a" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-NAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="NAME" class="required" id="mce-NAME">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_3aff75083c84f012673478808_175e779a1a" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fnames = new Array();var ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='NAME';ftypes[1]='text';
try {
    var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    jqueryLoaded=true;
} catch(err) {
    var jqueryLoaded=false;
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if (!jqueryLoaded) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    if (script.readyState && script.onload!==null){
        script.onreadystatechange= function () {
              if (this.readyState == 'complete') mce_preload_check();
        }    
    }
}

var err_style = '';
try{
    err_style = mc_custom_error_style;
} catch(e){
    err_style = '#mc_embed_signup input.mce_inline_error{border-color:#6B0505;} #mc_embed_signup div.mce_inline_error{margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 5px 10px; background-color:#6B0505; font-weight: bold; z-index: 1; color:#fff;}';
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style= document.createElement('style');
style.type= 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet) {
  style.styleSheet.cssText = err_style;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err_style));
}
head.appendChild(style);
setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);

var mce_preload_checks = 0;
function mce_preload_check(){
    if (mce_preload_checks>40) return;
    mce_preload_checks++;
    try {
        var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.form-n-validate.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
    try {
        var validatorLoaded=jQuery("#fake-form").validate({});
    } catch(err) {
        setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
        return;
    }
    mce_init_form();
}
function mce_init_form(){
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
      var options = { errorClass: 'mce_inline_error', errorElement: 'div', onkeyup: function(){}, onfocusout:function(){}, onblur:function(){}  };
      var mce_validator = $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
      $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").unbind('submit');//remove the validator so we can get into beforeSubmit on the ajaxform, which then calls the validator
      options = { url: 'http://worldacademy.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=3aff75083c84f012673478808&id=175e779a1a&c=?', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    beforeSubmit: function(){
                        $('#mce_tmp_error_msg').remove();
                        $('.datefield','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var txt = 'filled';
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                $(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                $(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        var bday = false;
                                        if (fields.length == 2){
                                            bday = true;
                                            fields[2] = {'value':1970};//trick birthdays into having years
                                        }
                                        if ( fields[0].value=='MM' && fields[1].value=='DD' && (fields[2].value=='YYYY' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else if ( fields[0].value=='' && fields[1].value=='' && (fields[2].value=='' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            if (/\[day\]/.test(fields[0].name)){
                                                this.value = fields[1].value+'/'+fields[0].value+'/'+fields[2].value;                                           
                                            } else {
                                                this.value = fields[0].value+'/'+fields[1].value+'/'+fields[2].value;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        $('.phonefield-us','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                            function(){
                                var fields = new Array();
                                var i = 0;
                                $(':text', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        fields[i] = this;
                                        i++;
                                    });
                                $(':hidden', this).each(
                                    function(){
                                        if ( fields[0].value.length != 3 || fields[1].value.length!=3 || fields[2].value.length!=4 ){
                                            this.value = '';
                                        } else {
                                            this.value = 'filled';
                                        }
                                    });
                            });
                        return mce_validator.form();
                    }, 
                    success: mce_success_cb
                };
      $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').ajaxForm(options);


    });
}
function mce_success_cb(resp){
    $('#mce-success-response').hide();
    $('#mce-error-response').hide();
    if (resp.result=="success"){
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
        $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });
    } else {
        var index = -1;
        var msg;
        try {
            var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
            if (parts[1]==undefined){
                msg = resp.msg;
            } else {
                i = parseInt(parts[0]);
                if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                    index = parts[0];
                    msg = parts[1];
                } else {
                    index = -1;
                    msg = resp.msg;
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            index = -1;
            msg = resp.msg;
        }
        try{
            if (index== -1){
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
            } else {
                err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
                html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

                var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
                var f = $(input_id);
                if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                    f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
                } else {
                    input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                    f = $().parent(input_id).get(0);
                }
                if (f){
                    $(f).append(html);
                    $(input_id).focus();
                } else {
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
                }
            }
        } catch(e){
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Now I change this link in two location i.e. on form submit and in javacript from

```
http://worldacademy.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=3aff75083c84f012673478808&id=175e779a1a&c=?
```

to the new link which is

```
http://worldtradeadvisors.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3aff75083c84f012673478808&amp;id=0f6cad50b6
```

But this is not working. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this

The link in javascript needed to be changed from

```
http://worldtradeadvisors.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3aff75083c84f012673478808&amp;id=0f6cad50b6
```

to

```
http://worldtradeadvisors.us7.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post-json?u=3aff75083c84f012673478808&id=0f6cad50b6&c=?
```